# Meteor: Display text only if roles == 'webmaster'

Tags: if-statement, meteor, handlebars.js, roles

I want to display information based on a user being iterated on a page.

I have the following template:

```
<template name="allUsers">
  <div>
    {{#each user}}
      {{username}}<br/>
      <!-- This is where I need some guidance -->
      {{#if roles == 'webmaster}} <!-- What's the correct way to do this? -->
        This user is a webmaster
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm using the alanning:roles package and in the server I have been sure to publish the roles field for users.  roles.[0] will return webmaster for now and roles.[1] returns admin...  But I know further down the line with adding roles it won't have the standard key of 0 = webmaster and 1 = admin.

Is there a way to just test IF the roles array contains 'webmaster' to be displayed on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a global template helper to help out with this.

```
Template.registerHelper( 'isUserInRole', function( userId, role ) {
    return Roles.userIsInRole(userId, role);
});

<template name="allUsers">
  <div>
    {{#each user}}
      {{username}}
      {{#if isUserInRole _id 'webmaster'}}
        This user is a webmaster
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**Edited based on the first comment.

Comment: Same thing as what S. 19LabG originally posted:

This refers to the current user logged in. My question was how to display the roles of each iterated user. This code will show every user to have a 'webmaster' role because my account is set as 'webmaster'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<template name="allUsers">
  <div>
    {{#each user}}
      {{username}}<br/>
      <!-- This is where I need some guidance -->
      {{#if roles.[1] == 'webmaster}} <!-- What's the correct way to do this? -->
        This user is a webmaster
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This refers to the current user logged in.  My question was how to display the roles of each iterated user.  This code will show every user to have a 'webmaster' role because my account is set as 'webmaster'.

Comment: So, if I understand your question you want to reach a particular element of the array. You could try to find the right syntax (I am pretty sure there was a question like that in stackoverflow) in order to check the particular element. I think the syntax was user.roles[0] or user.roles[1]. Try the code which I will include in the answer

Comment: In this case...  What if one user's roles are ['webmaster', 'admin'] and another user's roles are ['admin', 'webmaster'].  Your answer doesn't say why it should work.